# Diplay Lastest Record of a table - SQL MAX() function

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Final code:

```
$querySelect = "SELECT A.IdCliente, A.Data, A.IdPontos 
                FROM $tabela AS A INNER JOIN ( SELECT MAX(IdPontos) [ID] 
                FROM $tabela 
                WHERE IdCliente = $cliente2 AND IdPontos = $voucher ) 
                AS B ON B.ID = A.IdPontos
                ";

$resultSelect = mssql_query($querySelect) or die('Erros querying MSSQL SELECT');

//Show result
    while ( $record = mssql_fetch_array($resultSelect) )
{
    echo $record["IdCliente"] . ' - Código do Cliente<br />';
    echo $record["IdPontos"] . ' - Número do voucher do cliente<br />';
}
```

---

I'm trying to display just the lastest record (row) in a table, until now, I only could get all records of an expecific user. I used the MAX() function, but I got an error:

> Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: message: Column 'Clt_cadPontosFidelidade.IdCliente' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. (severity 16) in /home/storage/c/60/21/allantoledo/public_html/NovoApp/resgatar.php on line 36

My code:

```
$querySelect = "SELECT
            IdCliente, Data, MAX(IdPontos)
            FROM $tabela 
            WHERE IdCliente = $cliente2
            AND IdPontos = $voucher
           ";
```

And I cound't display the values of my array, they didn't appear.

Code:

```
$resultSelect = mssql_query($querySelect) or die('Erros querying MSSQL SELECT');

//Show result
    while ( $record = mssql_fetch_array($resultSelect) )
{
    echo $resultSelect["IdCliente"] . ' - Código do Cliente<br />';
    echo $resultSelect["IdPontos"] . ' - Número do voucher do cliente<br />';
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: How do you define "lastest row".  Your query is only selecting one value of `idPuntos`, but that appears to be what you want for the maximum value.

Comment: Each Insert has a number and the last record is the higher number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `order by` and `top 1`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 a.*
FROM $tabela a
WHERE a.IdCliente = $cliente2 AND a.IdPontos = $voucher
ORDER BY IdPontos DESC;
```

I do find it curious that you have only one value of `IdPontos`.  Perhaps there is another field that determines "the last row".

Comment: It worked. But It still don't displaying the value of the arrays. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

If you use an aggregate function without a group by, then it presumes it is for all rows. Because you have added the columns IdCliente and Data, it would need a group by:

```
        SELECT IdCliente, Data, MAX(IdPontos)
        FROM $tabela 
        WHERE IdCliente = $cliente2
        AND IdPontos = $voucher
        GROUP BY IdCliente, Data
```

But this would show more rows than you require. So you could join back to the IdPontos to get these, or use the TOP 1 as suggested.

Comment: With this code, I still geting all records of the user. But, thank you anyway! I'll try TOP 1 option.

Comment: You will, as per the group by. You'd need to return just the MAX I'd, then join back to get the data you require, so you're only looking at one record.

Comment: I don't know how to return / select this MAX(IdPontos). Could you tell me?

Comment: @ÁllanFidelisToledo try something like:         SELECT A.IdCliente, A.Data
FROM $tabela AS A
INNER JOIN 
(     
SELECT MAX(IdPontos) [ID]
FROM $tabela 
WHERE IdCliente = $cliente2
AND IdPontos = $voucher
) AS B ON B.ID = A.IdPontos

Comment: It worked very well, thank you man! I just Add one more column to SELECT A.IdPontos.